# Unable to unnest json file to create map in r?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyr

I am new to using `json` in r and wanted to create map using data from it but so far I am unable to bring it to usable data structure format.

This is what I have tried:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
ind_waterways <- jsonlite::fromJSON( url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/india-in-data/waterways/master/ind_waterways.json"))

ind_waterways
```

```
ind_waterways %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest()
```

but when I try to `unnest` it then I get error:

```
ind_waterways$features %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(coordinates)
```

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column `coordinates` doesn't exist. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: there is no `coordinates` column after the `as_tibble`.  In the second case, it is 'properties' and 'geometry'

Comment: @akrun when I was running `ind_waterways$features %>% map_if(is.data.frame, list)` then I was getting `type & coordinates` columns. I am trying to understand your answer below & running it and will accept it soon.

Comment: I did tested the function on a subset of data, but with the full data it is taking time

Comment: I updated with the ouptut I got.  Please check

Comment: yes, I ran the whole set and it took some time & just got the output now. I think I am getting out lat & long here as output in V1 & V2 which should be sufficient to plot. I Will accept the answer and will slowly decode ur answer step by step as I am new to json and will take some time to understand this.

Comment: it is because when you do `map(coordinates, as_tibble))` there is a default naming.  I should have usd `map(coordinates, ~ tibble(lat = .x[,1], lon = .x[,2]))`

Comment: yes this is even better, thanks again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, code uses the OP's solution until the conversion to `tibble`, then we do `unnest`ing of columns individually as the structure is a bit complex i.e. involves `matrix` as columns in a nested `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
out <- ind_waterways %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(crs = unlist(crs)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(features, names_repair = "unique") %>%
  unnest_wider(geometry) %>%
  unnest(names(.)[3:6]) %>%
  mutate(coordinates = map(coordinates, as_tibble)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(coordinates) %>%
  unnest(c(V1, V2))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 115,318 x 7
   type...1          crs   type...3    id type          V1    V2
   <chr>             <chr> <chr>    <int> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.6  34.6
 2 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.5  34.6
 3 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.4  34.7
 4 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.2  34.7
 5 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.2  34.8
 6 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.1  34.8
 7 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.1  34.8
 8 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.0  34.8
 9 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  77.0  34.8
10 FeatureCollection name  Feature      0 LineString  76.8  34.9
# … with 115,308 more rows
```

Comment: Yes I got the same output with your code & this looks good. Now I will try & understand 'ur code as I am totally new to json. Thanks alot @akrun for always helping me out. Really appreciate it :))